# Jupyter Shortcuts compatibility between EC2 and MacOS

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on an Ubuntu EC2 instance with Jupiter Notebook installed on it. I've noticed that some shortcuts are not working seamlessly from a Mac keyboard (e.g.: The Toggle comment one) 
I've tried to edit the shortcut manually but it does not work.

Any Idea on how to solve the issue?

Best

Answer (score 0):

Option+C works on all environments